# What's the advantage of NS_INLINE over static inline?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, static, inline

Looking at the define of `NS_INLINE` it seems that the advantage of using it over `static inline` is compiler compatibility, is that correct? Should `NS_INLINE` always be used instead of `static inline` on c functions in objective-c projects?

```
#if !defined(NS_INLINE)
    #if defined(__GNUC__)
        #define NS_INLINE static __inline__ __attribute__((always_inline))
    #elif defined(__MWERKS__) || defined(__cplusplus)
        #define NS_INLINE static inline
    #elif defined(_MSC_VER)
        #define NS_INLINE static __inline
    #elif TARGET_OS_WIN32
        #define NS_INLINE static __inline__
    #endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's for compiler compatibility, but I think it's more for the use of the frameworks than for your own code. You're free to use it, of course, but I wouldn't bother.

Comment: What if the code is for a library used by others, would you recommend using `NS_INLINE` then?

Comment: Is it going to be used on platforms other than Apple's? With GnuStep or the like? If not, then no. There's approximately zero chance that developing for Mac OS X or iOS will ever be incompatible with `static inline`.

Answer (score 23):

> Looking at the define of NS_INLINE it seems that the advantage of using it over static inline is compiler compatibility, is that correct?

Only in part. You must assess the dominant toolchain here, and ask "why was `static inline` *not* used, or why was it inadequate?". The dominant toolchain contains the attribute `__attribute__((always_inline))`. So there are really two parts to this:

- a) Compatibility So it adds compatibility for multiple compilers.
- b) Use of `__attribute__((always_inline))` in the dominant toolchain. `inline` has devolved to be a simple request to `inline`. With `always_inline`, the compiler can still reserve the right to not inline the function (for obvious reasons). However, it also says "trust me, I want this inlined -- compiler, inline this if possible". This attribute restores some of the ability to inline to the programmer. This can be used for performance, but I suspect (in this case) that it has more to do with reduction of the number of private exported functions, rather than performance requirements.

> Should NS_INLINE always be used instead of static inline in objective-c projects?

No. `__attribute__((always_inline))` should be reserved for people who have had a lot of experience optimizing programs, and with use of this facility. This attribute can be applied to C functions, C++ methods, and other static calls. It cannot be applied to ObjC class or instance methods (which are dynamic). I mention that because the compiler, optimizer, and LTO are very good at what they do. Meanwhile, improper use of inlining can have (any of) several performance penalties. The exception (for people who have not spent significant time optimizing) is of course when one takes the time to measure the differences it makes.

Comment: Thanks, very in-depth! I've updated my question slights to make it clear that I am talking about c functions in an objective-c project.

Comment: @keegan3d you're welcome. in fact, i'd assumed you were applying it to the right symbols. i mentioned objc methods as a side note (e.g. for any reader). however, the larger point i was *trying* to make was that there are good optimizers in the toolchain, and fairly recent advances in optimization (e.g. clang's LTO) which allow for very aggressive optimization of many C and C++ symbols -- even when the definitions are not visible to the compiler. these advances further increase the difficulty of hand tuning successfully (e.g. use of `__attribute__((always_inline))`).

Comment: What about the new `FOUNDATION_STATIC_INLINE` macro? That's just defined as `static __inline__`. Can I use that, i.e., is `static __inline__` the same as `static inline`?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale `__inline__` is just a retro compiler extension. You should just use the `inline` keyword, unless you need a compiler extension which predates standardization of the `inline` keyword in C (few objc devs will ever need this). but yes, `__inline__` is equivalent to `inline` in those contexts that come to mind (e.g. MSC-C90 and GCC-C90). In the example above, you probably see it for compatibility with other compilers -- and only for C and ObjC.